# VS2015 fails in one specific keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, ghostdoc

I'm using VS 2015 version 14.0.25425.01 update 3 with GhostDoc 5.1 installed.

I use Ctrl+Shift+D to document properties or methods, this was working great until a week or so  (I don't know if this has anything to do with the latest update to SSMS 2016).

Since last week when turn on my machine everything works great, but after awhile the shortcut stops working (if I change the action to another shortcut it works OK), the only way to make it work again is restarting the machine (assign it again, closing all the instances of VS does not work).

I exported my keyboard settings to see if something was using it and the only thing I found was this on the settings of SSMS:

```
<UserShortcuts>    
    <RemoveShortcut Command="Debug.ParallelStacks" Scope="Global">Ctrl+Shift+D, S</RemoveShortcut>
    ....
<UserShortcuts>
```

But in the keyboard settings of SSMS that action does not have a shortcut associated.

It's there a way i can find out whats happening? The ActivityLog of VS does not show anything obvious and neither the log of GhostDoc

PS: Is there a way to disable for goo the new Documentation Maintenance Toolbar?

Comment: I used the info in this [super user post](https://superuser.com/a/26844/10596), in my case was Jabber the culprit